# How can I change the text-color after choosing one option of the select-menu with css?

Tags: html, css, drop-down-menu

I have a registration for a website with a html select menu from which to choose between beeing called Mr. or Mrs. The text-color is grey and I want it to be black after choosing one of the options, like it happens with the usual input fields.

I've tried it with .anrede:focus (that works for the input fields), but that makes it grey again after choosing the next input field

```
            <div>
                <select id="anrede" class="anrede">
                    <option hidden>Anrede</option>
                    <option value="f">Frau</option>
                    <option value="m">Herr</option>
                </select>
            </div>
            <!--Vorname-->
            <div><input id="vname" type="text" class="input" placeholder="Vorname"></div>

.input{
border: 2px solid #AD974F;
border-radius: 4px;
margin-top: 15px;
```

}

```
.input:focus{
border: 2px solid #8E793E;
```

I want to solve it with CSS if that's possible, but i couldn't find any solution yet.

Comment: you need to use javascript change event where you can check the current value and then apply style to it.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply add jQuery to your project, like this:

```
<head>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/
     jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
```

Then just use the snippet below inside of `<script></script>` tags at the bottom of your HTML file.

You will also need to give each of your options an 'id' if you want to accomplish the bonus text-color-change for each option selected.

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
   $("#anrede").change(function(){
    // the code in here will be called if an option is selected

    // This line will change the options text-color to be whatever color you 
    // provide
    $(this).find('option').css('text-color', '#8E793E');
   });
});
```

Bonus:

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
  $("#anrede").change(function(){
  //If you want to change the color based on what option was selected you can 
  get them based on their id's and handle them accordingly 
  // EX: 
  var id = $(this).find("option:selected").attr("id");

  switch (id){
   case "Anrede":
   // Change the color for the Anrede option
   $(this).find(id).css('text-color', '#8E793E');
   break;
   .... // Add cases for each possible ID if needed
  }
 });
});
```